# Monitoring heartbeat centos

Tags: monitoring, cluster, heartbeat

I am using `HAproxy` on two servers and for high availability using `heartbeat` and everything is okay, but I want to monitoring `heartbeat` I have a long search and get `clustat` command but can't find it on server and found `cl_status` command found it on the server but can't give a important information like

- the member system status
- Heartbeat channel status
- Service status and which cluster system is running the service

Comment: Clustat is used by RHCS (RedHat Cluster Suite) and is distributed by cman package, so you cannot use that command with heartbeat which is another clustering stack. Which version of heartbeat are you using, because answer depends on that.

Comment: heartbeat-3.0.4-2

Answer (score 1):

If you use heartbeat 3.0.x from EPEL, then you should use crm_mon command. This will show you all the information you want:

```
# crm_mon -1
```

Its output includes the number of nodes, uname, uuid, status, the resources configured in your cluster, and the current status of each.

If you want to group resources by node, run a command like this:

```
# crm_mon --group-by-node --inactive
```

You can also output into XML.

Comment: `-bash: rm_mon: command not found`

Comment: you missed letter C

Comment: sorry my comment her wrong
`-bash: crm_mon: command not found`

Comment: ah sorry, I did a wrong presumption about heartbeat, I'll edit my comment

Comment: cl_status is all you have, crm_mon is actually from heartbeat v2 which is now pacemaker... my mistake, take a look at:
http://linux.die.net/man/1/cl_status

Comment: `cl_status` not give me a good info 
like all node are dead

Comment: unfortunately that's all that you got for that clustering stack. maybe you should consider switching to RedHat Cluster Suite

Comment: pacemaker is better I used it in HA Apache but now I don't have time to replace heartbeat :)